# K Inverse Pairs Array - Brute Force

Tags: python, dynamic-programming

For an integer array `nums`, an inverse pair is a pair of integers `[i, j]` where `0 <= i < j < nums.length` and `nums[i] > nums[j]`.

Given two integers n and k, return the number of different arrays consisting of numbers from 1 to n such that there are exactly k inverse pairs. Since the answer can be huge, return it modulo \$10^9 + 7\$.

https://leetcode.com/problems/k-inverse-pairs-array/solution/

Brute Force Solution:

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations

class Solution:
    def kInversePairs(self, n: int, k: int) -> int:
        array = [x for x in range(1,n+1)]
        array_permutations = list(permutations(array))
        memoized = {}
        count = 0
        for each_permutation in array_permutations:
            each_permutation = list(each_permutation)
            if self.has_exactly_k_inverse_pair(k, each_permutation, memoized):
                count += 1
        return count % 1000000007


    def has_exactly_k_inverse_pair(self, k, array, memoized):
        count = 0
        list_of_sequential_pairs = combinations(array, 2)
        for item_i, item_j in list_of_sequential_pairs:
            cached = memoized.get((item_i, item_j), None)
            if not cached:
                result = self.is_inverse_pair((item_i, item_j))
                if result:
                    memoized[(item_i, item_j)] = result
                    count += 1
            else:
                count += 1

            if count > k:
                return False
        return count == k
    

    def is_inverse_pair(self, tup):
        return tup[0] > tup[1]
```

I am looking for code review just for the brute force solutions. I am looking to get constructive feedback mainly with:

- Using `memoized` dictionary for storing `True` entries only.
- Being able to pass memoized and update it.
- Using tuples as keys in Python.
- Overall best coding practices.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**The memoization is not helping**. In fact, it's slowing things down
considerably. I executed your code for all pairs of `n` and `k` from `0`
through `9`, inclusive: it took 16 seconds on my computer. Then I commented out the memoization
infrastructure and the `is_inverse_pair()` method and instead just tested for
`item_i > item_j` directly: it finished in 6 seconds and got the same result.
This failure of memoization was caused by overfactoring: in almost all
situations, it hurts both readability and speed to write a function to perform
simple mathematical evaluations. I haven't benchmarked it recently, but calling
any function (even a no-op) is almost certainly slower than comparing two
integers. And when you're doing something that's already fast, there's no
benefit to memoization: I would not be surprised if even a dict-lookup is
slower than integer comparison (again, I haven't benchmarked it).

**The check for `count > k` is helping**. How do I know? Same benchmarking
setup: it takes 10 seconds without the guard.

**If you care about speed, make it easy to test and measure**. My first step
when working on your code was to exercise it with a test case across a variety
of inputs (as described), put everything in a dict mapping `(n, k)` inputs to
resulting outputs, print that dict and then put it into a big `EXPECTED`
constant in the code. This quickly gave me an automated way to make sure my
changes did not mess anything up, and also an easy way to do some simple speed
comparisons as I experimented. This programming habit was learned the hard way,
through trial, much error, and even more pain. I encourage you to start
adopting similar habits, both in your code and in your coding questions on
sites like this (give readers some helpful test code to work with, not just
your proposed answer).

**Don't convert generators to actual sequences needlessly**. You don't need
`array_permutations` as an actual list, because you can iterate directly over
the values yielded by `permutations(array)`. Doing so speeds things up a bit
more: 4.8 seconds for the same benchmark. And the same thing applies to
`each_permutation`: you don't need to listify it. Instead, just pass the
generator to the next function, where it will be iterated directly without the
cost of creating an actual list. Dropping that change got my simple benchmark
down to 4.2 seconds. You also don't need `array` to be a list. Just give the
range directly to `permutations()` (because `n` is small in my benchmark, this
change had no observable speed-effect for me, but the same principle would apply
if `n` were large).

**Tuples make great dict keys**. You asked about this, and it's an excellent
thing to have in your tool kit. For example, sometimes `d[x, y]` is a more
convenient way to organize data than `d[x][y]`. Note also that parentheses are
not required: you don't need to use `d[(x, y)]`. The comma creates the tuple,
not the parentheses.

**Speaking over overfactoring**. You can get another small speed boost
by dropping `has_exactly_k_inverse_pair()`. Function calls take time,
so if you're really wanting to eek out gains, inline the code. Of course,
that can come at a readability cost, but in this case (given the changes
noted above), I don't feel too bad about it.

Here's the code I ended up with:

```
from itertools import permutations, combinations

EXPECTED = {
    (0, 0): 1, (0, 1): 0, (0, 2): 0, (0, 3): 0, (0, 4): 0, (0, 5): 0, (0, 6): 0, (0, 7): 0, (0, 8): 0, (0, 9): 0,
    (1, 0): 1, (1, 1): 0, (1, 2): 0, (1, 3): 0, (1, 4): 0, (1, 5): 0, (1, 6): 0, (1, 7): 0, (1, 8): 0, (1, 9): 0,
    (2, 0): 1, (2, 1): 1, (2, 2): 0, (2, 3): 0, (2, 4): 0, (2, 5): 0, (2, 6): 0, (2, 7): 0, (2, 8): 0, (2, 9): 0,
    (3, 0): 1, (3, 1): 2, (3, 2): 2, (3, 3): 1, (3, 4): 0, (3, 5): 0, (3, 6): 0, (3, 7): 0, (3, 8): 0, (3, 9): 0,
    (4, 0): 1, (4, 1): 3, (4, 2): 5, (4, 3): 6, (4, 4): 5, (4, 5): 3, (4, 6): 1, (4, 7): 0, (4, 8): 0, (4, 9): 0,
    (5, 0): 1, (5, 1): 4, (5, 2): 9, (5, 3): 15, (5, 4): 20, (5, 5): 22, (5, 6): 20, (5, 7): 15, (5, 8): 9, (5, 9): 4,
    (6, 0): 1, (6, 1): 5, (6, 2): 14, (6, 3): 29, (6, 4): 49, (6, 5): 71, (6, 6): 90, (6, 7): 101, (6, 8): 101, (6, 9): 90,
    (7, 0): 1, (7, 1): 6, (7, 2): 20, (7, 3): 49, (7, 4): 98, (7, 5): 169, (7, 6): 259, (7, 7): 359, (7, 8): 455, (7, 9): 531,
    (8, 0): 1, (8, 1): 7, (8, 2): 27, (8, 3): 76, (8, 4): 174, (8, 5): 343, (8, 6): 602, (8, 7): 961, (8, 8): 1415, (8, 9): 1940,
    (9, 0): 1, (9, 1): 8, (9, 2): 35, (9, 3): 111, (9, 4): 285, (9, 5): 628, (9, 6): 1230, (9, 7): 2191, (9, 8): 3606, (9, 9): 5545,
}

def main():
    LIMIT = 10
    got = {
        (n, k) : Solution().kInversePairs(n, k)
        for n in range(LIMIT)
        for k in range(LIMIT)
    }
    assert got == EXPECTED

class Solution:

    def kInversePairs(self, n: int, k: int) -> int:
        count = 0
        for perm in permutations(range(1, n + 1)):
            n = 0
            for item_i, item_j in combinations(perm, 2):
                if item_i > item_j:
                    n += 1
                    if n > k:
                        break
            if n == k:
                count += 1
        return count % 1000000007

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```